# ExecuteNonQuery() from c# throwing exception - arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have a weird situation, I have a SP being called from my C# application through ADO.Net, the SP doesn't return any data. It is throwing the below exception, but when i execute the SP with the same parameters in SSMS it runs with out any issues.

There is no other actions apart from calling the SP in my C# code.

Error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Arithmetic overflow error for type int, value = 2344000000.000000

IN C# code the SP is called using ExecuteNonQuery() and it throws Arithematic overflow exception.

I changed it to ExecuteScalar() and there is no error, which i could confirm that the issue is with either sql server or ADO.Net as SP execution in SSMS always executed without any issues.

As the SP doesn't return any data, ADO.NET ExecuteNonQuery will get the number of rows affected as return value and may be this number is bigger than Power(2,31) and could be the reason of Arithematic overflow exception but i don't have more than Power(2,31) rows in my DB tables. This is just my guess.

Answer (score 0):

This means the value is too big for int type so it overflows

the max value for signed int is 2,147,483,647

so 2344000000 will return this error

Comment: Hi Dung Le,

But the SP executes successfully in SSMS and it doesn't return any values, so this exception is happening after the SP execution and control passes back to the ADO.Net call.

Comment: Hi @HarinathBoyapalli can you try again with ExecuteNonQuery and use a small number in the request to check if this will occur or not

Comment: The input parameters are the date range and other string values, also none of the values in my tables are so big and with the same parameter values the execution of the SP in SSMS is successfull.

Answer (score 0):

The issue, I'm guessing, is that `2344000000` is the number of rows affected. `ExecuteNonQuery()` returns that as an `int`, whereas `ExecuteScalar()` can return that as a `long` (boxed as an `object`) so no overflow happens.